# Decision tree: Perfect classification with (a dicotomic) class noise at 100%, but almost null prediction with noise at 99%. (Tried 2 alg in R). Why?

Tags: r, machine-learning, weka, cart, decision-tree

I am using a dataset with a dicotomic class and testing how noise affects the decision tree j48 - from Rweka, using R - performance. I´m adding noise, and using confindence factors from 0.01 to 0.5 along the experiment.

As the class is dicotomic, it makes perfect sense that the worst performance of the training set is at 50%, being the class dicotomic.

Now... as the validation goes down, I´ve some points where the accuracy is almost perfect when the noise is total. How can I explain that?

[image]

**Red is for the training set; Blue for the validation (80/20)**

accuracy = (correctly predicted class / total testing class) × 100% OR, The percentage of correctly classified instances (TP + TN)/(TP + TN + FP + FN). where TP, FN, FP and TN represent the number of true positives, false negatives, false positives and true negatives, respectively.

The dataset I´m using is a random sample (10%) of this one https://www.kaggle.com/ludobenistant/hr-analytics

Here´s my code:

```
library(arules)
library(RWeka)
library(readr)
library(caret)
library(caTools)


setwd("C:\\Users\\Lucas\\Desktop\\AA")
inputFileName = "hr.csv"

ruido = function( datasetName, percentage ) {
  hr = read_csv(datasetName)

  sample = sample.split(hr$left, SplitRatio = percentage / 100)
  toModify = subset(hr, sample == TRUE)
  NotModify = subset(hr, sample == FALSE)

  toModify$left = sapply(toModify$left, function(x) !x )

  new_hr = rbind(toModify, toNotModify)

  output = strsplit(datasetName, "[.]")
  outputFileName = paste0(output[[1]][1], '_ruido_', percentage, '.', output[[1]][2])

  write.csv(new_hr, file = outputFileName, row.names=FALSE)
  outputFileName
}

set.seed(101) 
percentages = seq(0, 100 )
confidenceFactors = seq(0.05, 0.5, 0.05)

dataset = read.csv( inputFileName, sep = "," )

sample = sample.split(dataset$left, SplitRatio = .8)
train = subset(dataset, sample == TRUE)
test  = subset(dataset, sample == FALSE)

dir.create(file.path("C:\\Users\\Lucas\\Desktop\\AA", "datasets\\5"))
write.csv(train, file = "datasets\\5\\HR_train.csv", row.names=FALSE)
write.csv(test, file = "datasets\\5\\HR_test.csv", row.names=FALSE)

sizeResults = data.frame( "CF" = double(), "Percentage" = double(), "Value" = integer(), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
accuracyResults = data.frame( "CF" = double(), "Method" = character(), "Percentage" = double(), "Value" = integer(), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

for( percentage in percentages ){

    percentage = percentage / 100

    # load training dataset
    outputFile = ruido( "datasets\\5\\HR_train.csv", percentage * 100 )
    training = read.csv( outputFile )
    training$number_project = as.factor( training$number_project )
    training$time_spend_company = as.factor( training$time_spend_company )


    for( c in confidenceFactors ){
      # create tree
      print( paste0("Decision tree for: ", "percentage=", percentage, ", CF=", c) )
      tree = J48( as.factor(left) ~ ., training, control = Weka_control(M=2, C=c) )
      treeSize = tree$classifier$numElements()
      sizeResults = rbind(sizeResults, data.frame(CF=c, Percentage=percentage, Value=treeSize))

      # test tree
      pred <- predict(tree, test, type='class')
      trainingAccuracy = summary(tree)$details[[1]]
      testAccuracy = confusionMatrix(table(test$left, pred))
      accuracyResults = rbind(accuracyResults, data.frame(CF=c, Percentage=percentage, Method="Entrenamiento", Value=trainingAccuracy))
      accuracyResults = rbind(accuracyResults, data.frame(CF=c, Percentage=percentage, Method="Validaci�n", Value=testAccuracy$overall[[1]] * 100))
    }
}


ggplot(data=sizeResults, aes(x=Percentage, y=Value)) +
  geom_point() +
  ylab("Nodes") + # Set axis labels
  scale_colour_hue(name="")       # Set legend title  

ggplot(data=accuracyResults, aes(x=Percentage, y=Value, group=Method, color=Method)) +
  geom_point() +
  ylab("Accuracy") + # Set axis labels
  scale_colour_hue(name="")
```

Comment: You might want to ask this on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: And multiply posting the exact same question is not really smiled upon